# CSS Only Ellipse (i.e. "...") Collapsing & Expanding

Tags: jquery, html, css, outlook

When a user clicks an ellipse, I want some text to display.  The following example shows a clean implementation of what I have in mind using jquery.  This example shows expanding and collapsing, the CSS solution

```js
$('.collapse').click( function(){
  if( $(this).attr('dataStatus') != "visible" )
      {$(this)
       .html('{ ' + $(this).attr('dataText') + ' }')
        .attr('dataStatus','visible')
      }
   else
      {$(this)
       .html('. . .')
        .attr('dataStatus','hidden')
      }   
});
```

```css
.collapse {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Tom <a class="collapse" href="#" dataText="never">. . .</a> runs.
```

I want to achieve the same result without using any javascript.  (Ultimately, I'm trying to find a way to recreate this function in intra-office emails processed by Outlook, but I'd be satisfied with a simple pure CSS answer even if it couldn't work in Outlook).

My first instinct was to use the "visited" tag, along with an "after" and "before" content content tag.  And I found some outdated [support](https://css-tricks.com/put-checkmarks-next-to-visted-links-with-pure-css/) for this approach, but ultimately privacy concerns have lead "visited" to be severely limited.

Can anyone think of another CSS/HTML based implementation that would achieve the desired result?  Perhaps [something](http://jsfiddle.net/thurstanh/emtAm/2/) involving lists or form elements.  The simpler the better, given that my ultimate goal is to get this working in Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I came up with.

```css
/**
Initial Setup
**/

.ellipsis-content,
.ellipsis-toggle input {
  display: none;
}
.ellipsis-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/**
Checked State
**/

.ellipsis-toggle input:checked + .ellipsis {
  display: none;
}
.ellipsis-toggle input:checked ~ .ellipsis-content {
  display: inline;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias
  <label class="ellipsis-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="ellipsis">...</span>
    <span class="ellipsis-content">illum mollitia quas beatae sit dolor et architecto ab voluptatum</span>
  </label>voluptate in incidunt unde voluptates maiores enim inventore rerum, nulla quae.</p>
```

**Support** - IE 9+, Chrome, Firefox, Opera 9+, Safari 3+.

Comment: I like that you got just the ellipses to trigger a state change. Nice example with the highlighting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a checkbox.

```css
.eli {
  position:relative;
}
.eli input {
  opacity:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
.eli input + .sm {
  display:inline-block;
}
.eli input:checked + .sm {
  display:none;
}
.eli input + .sm + .lg {
  display:none;
}
.eli input:checked + .sm + .lg {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class=eli>
<input type="checkbox">Tom <span class="sm">. . .</span> <span class="lg">{never}</span> runs
</span>
```

Note this is less like your sample code than @PraveenPuglia's answer below, which allows you to just click the ellipses to toggle. This solution causes the whole block to trigger a state change.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with focus or active

**CSS** and **HTML**

```css
.collapse:focus .dataBlank,
.collapse:active .dataBlank{
  display:none;
}
.collapse .dataText{
  display:none;
}
.collapse:focus .dataText,
.collapse:active .dataText{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
Tom <a class="collapse" href="javascript:void(0)" dataText="">
<span class="dataBlank">. . .</span>
<span class="dataText">{ never }</span>
</a> runs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:before` or `:after`](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) pseudo-class in combination with `:hover` or [`:target`](https://designshack.net/articles/css/targetcss/)

```
.x:hover:before { content:'has the'; }
.x:before { content:'...' }

#z:target:before { content:'has the'; }
#z:before { content:'...'; }
```

### SNIPPET

```css
.x, .y {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.x:hover:before {
  content: 'has the';
  color: red;
}
.x:before {
  content: '...';
  transition: color .35s ease-in;
}
#z:target:before {
  content: 'has the';
  color: red;
}
#z:before {
  content: '...';
  transition: color 1.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
Tom <a class="x" href="#"></a> runs.

<br/><br/>

Sally <a class="y" href="#z">

    <span id="z"></span>

</a> runs too.
```

Answer (score 0):

`:focus` , `text-overflow` , `tabindex` and switching the block formating context : `inline`<>`inline-block` can help.  **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zqXRdK)**

Your html can turn to be :   `<p>Tom <b tabindex="0">{ never }</b> runs.</p>` CSS will do the dots and hide/show.

```css
b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.25em;
  text-indent: -0.35em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: red;
}
b:focus {
  display: inline;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to toggle hide/show text or dots below: NOJS</p>
<p>Here is a <b tabindex="0"> text to show or not ?</b> Use of tabindex and focus.</p>
<hr/>
<p>Tom <b tabindex="0">{ never }</b> runs.</p>
```