# :target selector on dynamic generated element not affect

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors

My test shows that the `:target` selector effect on elements who exist in the DOM when page loaded only. Am I right?

I can't create a snippet here because I can't call the iframe's snippet with hash (`#`) so you can see the issue here:

http://output.jsbin.com/vixave#new_element

**HTML Button**

```
<button onclick="addElement()">Add element</button>
```

**CSS**

```css
div:target {
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function addElement() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="new_element">New element</div><br /><a href="#new_element">highlight</a>';  
}
```

In this demo you can see that after you click on the button and the div `#new_element` added to the body, he doesn't "get" the style. Only when you click on the link which call again **to the same URL**, the style will be apply.

**Update**

Further @BoltClock♦'s comment, this happens in Chrome and FireFox but in IE (SO strange) it's working as expected.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. It's not a direct pseudo class like `:hover`. It's sorta like an enhanced `target` attribute that's common in anchors.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks. Do you have referense (official document maybe?) Thanks..

Comment: https://designshack.net/articles/css/targetcss/ was enlightening, it's not offical though just an article that explains it better than MDN.  I also just used `:target` in a recent post http://stackoverflow.com/a/37223453/2813224

Comment: OK I will check this. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, sir. Btw, there was a gentleman that mentioned that you're replicating the target element's id. So it's expected that the first of the identical id `#new_element` will be targeted while the duplicates are ignored. It's the way the browser keeps it's sanity when confronted with identical ids. Maybe change the id into a class?

Comment: This make sense. The demo in the question is only an example. In my real app the `id`s are unique. How can you use `:target` with class instead of id? Or maybe I didn't understand you correctly..

Comment: I never tried class, I was curious and lazy. I figured you have an example already :P Never mind I just reread that article and it uses IDs and fragments.

Comment: Interesting. This behavior occurs in both Firefox and Chrome - on IE and Microsoft Edge it works as expected and matches automatically without you having to click highlight.

Comment: @Mosh Feu: You can't. Both fragment identifiers and id selectors target unique elements (that's why they share the same syntax) by design.

Comment: @zer00ne: Except even when there is only one such element with the id the :target pseudo doesn't match it until you click highlight. So the issue isn't related to duplicate ids (and it's probably why the previous user deleted their comment).

Comment: I wonder if it's possible in an indirect way say like descendants of `:target`?

Comment: @zer00ne: Absolutely. Only the element that's matched by :target needs to have the corresponding id. So you can say all descendants of the :target element, as long as the ancestor is the one that contains the matching id. My point is that :target cannot match an element with a corresponding class (and not id) attribute.

Comment: @BoltClock Agreed 100%. I'm liking this `:target` http://jsbin.com/yitijoh/1/edit?html,css,js,output If you create more after it's been activated the style is persistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying styles of `:target` selectors when a fragment (the string after a `#` in an URL) is present is the correct behaviour.

The specified behaviour can be found in the W3C [Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) and [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) specifications.

> **6.6.2. The target pseudo-class :target**
>
> Some URIs refer to a location within a resource. This kind of URI ends with a "number sign" (#) followed by an anchor identifier (called the fragment identifier).
>
> URIs with fragment identifiers link to a certain element within the document, known as the target element. For instance, here is a URI pointing to an anchor named section_2 in an HTML document:
>
> http://example.com/html/top.html#section_2
>
> A target element can be represented by the :target pseudo-class. If the document's URI has no fragment identifier, then the document has no target element.

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo

When the document loads and there's no valid `name` or `id` attribute according to the below alogorithm, the document has no valid fragment identifier.

> **5.6.9 Navigating to a fragment identifier**
>
> ...
>
> 5. If there is an element in the DOM that has an ID exactly equal to decoded fragid, then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.
> 6. No decoded fragid: If there is an a element in the DOM that has a name attribute whose value is exactly equal to fragid (not decoded fragid), then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid

However, *it seems to be unspecified* how vendors should deal with inserted nodes with an `id` or `name` attribute that equals to the URL fragment (that would make a valid fragment identifier while loading/navigating the document).

Comment: So why IE works? It's really strange. Also, usually in css, the styles applys on any content any time. Why this is the only topic that occur only in page load?

Comment: "The :target selector is applied when the document has a valid fragment identidier [sic]" #new_element is a valid fragment identifier according to the URI grammar, so why does it not match the target element right away? Also, the text from the HTML spec that you've quoted doesn't seem relevant - there is no navigation occurring here.

Comment: Changed the wording. I read the html5 spec multiple times and was unable to find a specification what happens to the documents fragment identifier when manipulating the DOM. So was I when searching the DOM specs. Since browsers behave differently and it's not specified you can't even tell this a bug.

Comment: The behavior doesn't follow the spec. Basically every vendor half-assed the implementation of :target. For example, there are open bugs in every browser for :target not respecting hash changes using the history API. It's a mess